# Referencing inside embedded documents in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I want to get some feedback on doing some MongoDB data design.  I've never really worked with it before, so if my design looks insane please let me know.

I have a concept for a user and the activities that a user performs. There needs to be an address for both the user and the activities they perform and the activities that they perform are exclusive to that user. Since the activiities will never overlap, the addresses shouldn't either.

My initial data structure looks something like this:

```
User : {
  # User data,
  address : {
    # address data
  },
  address : {
    # address data,
    home : true
  },
  activity : {
    # activity data,
    _address_id: #referenced address within user
  },
  activity : {
    # activity data,
    _address_id: #referenced address within user
  },
}
```

There is the assumption that the activity could have been performed at home.

Is there a better way to do this?  Should I just embed address inside activity as well as user?  Should I completely remove this from the user model?

This all is coming together in a Rails application using Mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is perfectly fine - document oriented databases are meant to be used like this. You should not repeat the address inside every activity since you will end up wasting space.

```
User : {
  # User data,
  address_<id> : {
    # address data
  },
  address_<id> : {
    # address data,
    home : true
  },

  activity : {
    # activity data,
    _address_id: #referenced address within user
  },
  activity : {
    # activity data,
    _address_id: #referenced address within user
  },
}
```

There are just two things that you need to take care of:
 1. Dont retrieve the entire document for a single activity
 2. Make sure that the document does not exceed the maximum size (or recompile)